# How to properly sanitise an array of user supplied data for JSON output?

Tags: php, arrays, json, encoding

**My code**

I have a function `get_points_table()` that returns an array like so:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [player] => steve
            [points] => 10
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [player] => jess
            [points] => 7
        )

)
```

I would like to pass this array as JSON to a JavaScript script to output as HTML.

My current script looks like this:

```
<?php 
    require_once 'db.php';
    $points_table = get_points_table($dbh);
    echo json_encode($points_table);
?>
```

**My problem**

My understanding is that if I don't sanitise the data before echo'ing it back, there is a security risk posed by a player setting their username to something like `steve<script>alert()</script>` or using some other combinations of special characters.

My research suggests I need to use some combination of `htmlentities()` and/or `htmlspecialchars()` to safely output the data. However `htmlentities()` does not return utf8 encoded data, so I also need to use `utf8_encode()` in order for `json_encode()` to understand it. `htmlentities()` also does not allow you to pass an array as a value.

**What I've tried**

I've tried various combinations of `array_walk()`, `array_walk_recursive()` and `array_map()` to apply `htmlentities()` to each value of my array but to no success. I've also tried accessing the values in nested `foreach` loops to no success either. e.g.:

```
foreach($points_table as $key=>value) {
    htmlspecialchars($value);
    htmlentities($value);
    utf8_encode($value);
}

echo json_encode($points_table);
```

**What I need**

I would like to know how to sanitise my array so I can safely pass it as JSON to be output as HTML, even if the user sets their username to something like `steve<script>alert()</script><php echo "hello world";?> ;-- - &%00`

Ideally I would like to do this so that the end result has the username in human readable format without converting symbols to html entities (i.e. `steve<script>` not `steve"&lt;script&gt;"`)

This feels like a very common thing developers would do and should have a simple and easy answer, but I have done much searching and cannot work it out for myself.

Comment: You need to use prepared statements first when you insert data in the db and then when you fetch them back

Comment: The data comes from the db? Does the user submit this data to the db?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius and @LelioFaieta thanks for your comments. The data is coming from a db. I am using prepared statements to submit the data to the db:


`$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO players (username, password) VALUES (:username, :password);");

$stmt->bindParam(":username", $_POST['username']);

$stmt->bindParam(":password", $password);

if($stmt->execute()) {
\\do stuff
}`


My understanding was prepared statements only sanitise data going into the db, but that the data requires re-sanitisation when coming out. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, a prepared statement is used to mitigate the threat of user supplied input when adding to the db and does not have a use in output from db. The JSON data can be manipulated by the user all he/she wants in Javascript - it is on their computer and will not affect anyone else

Comment: What about client side issues like XSS, CSRF, etc?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid html entities? They are necessary to avoid XSS, and don't affect how the data is displayed to the enduser.